# C# ¿ función que muestre la posición de un numero entero, ingresando por teclado?

Tags: c#

Por ejemplo: 34560  y quiero saber la posición Nº 2 que es 4 "el 2do imprime"

otro ejemplo:       13050 ingreso por teclado “4” imprime 5
"se me hace difícil entender la lógica"

Comment: Por favor siempre agrega el código que tengas ya desarrollado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Un truco sería transformar ese número a cadena y trabajar a partir de él:

```
public static int getValueFromIndex(int number, int index){
    string miCadena = number + "";
    char caracter = miCadena[index];
    return (int) Char.GetNumericValue(caracter);
  }
```